# Sleep mode in windows 8

Tags: windows-8.1, sleep

I'm facing a sleep mode problem in windows 8.1. 
In fact, my computer is unable to wake from sleep mode. When waking from sleep mode, it reboots and naturally, I lose all unsaved data.
Can somebody help me fix this ?

Comment: Is the machine up to date with drivers and windows update? Does the event viewer show anything?

Comment: Information about the power supply and CPU is required to help

Comment: Can you please try doing refresh process in Windows 8.1  so that if there is any issue with installation would get fixed during this process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your **Power Supply**. it can't handle the system power while waking up.

I also had this issue with mine and it just solved when i replaced it with a higher-watt one.

By the way before changing PU check if your system **BIOS** is up-to-date or not. if not try first with updating.

Comment: Thanks @Sdghasemi. I fix it by installing the support assistant of HP (it's the mark of the PC). This software helped me update my drivers and the BIOS and also install missing drivers. Thank you all.